# How to change the polygon area being displayed upon pressing a button in Flutter WEB

Tags: flutter, google-maps, web

I am making a flutter web application that displays the routes based on which button is being pressed. I did this by showing the polygon areas based on a hardcoded List routes. e.g.

```
class Routes{
   List<LatLng> route1 = [ 
      LatLng(x,y),
      LatLng(x,y),
      ...
   ];

   List<LatLng> route2 = [ 
      LatLng(x,y),
      LatLng(x,y),
      ...
   ];
}
```

I created a maps widget that accepts the route choice and renders the map accordingly:

```
class _GoogleMapState extends State<GoogleMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String htmlId = "7";

    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {
      final cameraPosition = LatLng(14.653836, 121.068427);

      final mapOptions = MapOptions()
        ..zoom = 16
        ..center = cameraPosition
        ..clickableIcons = false
        ..streetViewControl = false
      ;

      final elem = DivElement()
        ..id = htmlId
        ..style.width = "100%"
        ..style.height = "100%"
        ..style.border = 'none';

      final map = GMap(elem, mapOptions);

      switch (widget.route) {
        case 0:
          Polygon(PolygonOptions()
            ..paths = Routes.route1
            ..visible = true
            ..map = map
            ..fillOpacity = 0.0
            ..strokeColor = '#757A00'
          );
          break;
        case 1:
          Polygon(PolygonOptions()
            ..paths = Routes.route2
            ..visible = true
            ..map = map
            ..fillOpacity = 0.0
            ..strokeColor = '#F57F17'
          );
          break;
      }
      return elem;
    });

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: htmlId);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I made a switch case created the polygon based on the route id (0 or 1) being passed. This works when I load the map for the first time. But when I click another button that sets the route id to another value, nothing changes. Here is how I call the map:

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  int route_choice = 0;

  void _setRoute(int choice){
    setState(() {
      route_choice = choice;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              color: AppColors.secondaryBg,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: route_choice != 0 ? (){
                          _setRoute(0);
                        } : null,
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.directions_bus,
                            color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: route_choice != 1 ? (){
                          _setRoute(1);
                        } : null,
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.directions_bus,
                            color: Colors.red
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              child: GoogleMap(route: route_choice),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```